# Linux terminal print weird characters when using curses library

Tags: ncurses, curses, xterm, python-curses

When trying to run stuff like
https://github.com/asciimoo/drawille/blob/master/examples/rotating_cube.py

Using my normal user I always get weird characters like

`M-bM- ~@M-bM- ~@M-bM- ~@M-bM- ~@M-bM- ~@M-bM- ~@M-bM- ~@M-bM- ~@M-bM- ~@M-bM- ~@M-bM-!~OM-bM- ~IM-bM- ~IM-bM- ~IM-bM- ~IM-bM- ~IM-bM- ~IM-bM- ~IM-bM- ~IM-bM- ~IM-bM-
~IM-bM- ~IM-bM- ~IM-bM- ~IM-bM- ~IM-bM- ~IM-bM- ~IM-bM- ~IM-bM- ~IM-bM- ~IM-bM-!~GM-bM- ~@M-bM- ~@M-bM- ~@M-bM- ~@M-bM- ~@M-bM- ~@M-bM- ~@M-bM- ~@M-bM- ~@
M-bM- ~@M-bM- ~@M-bM- ~@M-bM- ~@M-bM- ~@M-bM- ~@M-bM- ~@M-bM- ~@M-bM- ~@M-bM- ~@M`

when running using `root` looks normal, my terminal prints unicode characters correctly when doing stuff like

`python -c 'print unichr(0x28ff)'`
or
`echo -e '\u285a'`

and $TERM is set to `xterm` in both user environments, any hint would be welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your "normal user" doesn't have the locale set so that ncurses sees that it supports UTF-8 encoding.  To see the difference, run the `locale` command as your normal user, and compare it with the output when running as root.

The **`M`**, by the way, means "meta", which denotes a character with the eighth (most-significant) bit set.  Back in the day when 7-bit ASCII was common, and 8-bit characters relatively new, some people decided to treat that specially.  If your locale is not set (i.e., POSIX), that's essentially 7-bit ASCII.

Some of that (including the use of **`M-`** as a prefix) is mentioned in the manual page for [`unctrl`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-unctrl_wunctrl).

Regarding the followup (which relies upon information not in the question), that's an old problem with Python which I'd thought was fixed.  As I pointed out in *[python+ncurses: I can't display accents](https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/593693-python-ncurses-i-cant-display-accents)*, Python doesn't really distinguish between **`ncurses`** and **`ncursesw`** based on their ***interfaces***, but only their ***name***, and that some other components may load the wrong name before you get to the curses module:

> It's more complicated than that: python's loading "ncurses"
>   dynamically.
>
> It doesn't matter much (to python) which one it loads, but it's
>   specifying the library name explicitly. At the same time, some other
>   packages (such as readline) are *separately* loading the ncurses library
>   - and they also specify a library name. Rather than abstracting that
>   stuff out to another (more easily changed) level, it's embedded in the code.
>
> If the initialization script is changed to load "ncursesw" then python
>   can use ncursesw without further change. There are a few patches to the
>   configuration that I've seen mentioned in the bug reports to enable
>   python to do this. Those are patches to python of course...
>
> (this was a topic of discussion on this newsgroup about a year ago).

Comment: Hi Thomas, `diff <(locale) <(sudo locale)` shows no difference hence both are the same, will try to see if locale stay the same within python context and will take a look to unctrl to understand better what's going on and try to find where the configuration issue is...

Comment: Still unlucky, `python -c "import locale; print(locale.getdefaultlocale())"` with both users print `('en_IE', 'UTF-8')`, the same result when adding that to a script using curses

Answer (score 0):

Googling finally fixed the issue by reinstalling the python 3.4.3 interpreter, looks like the python curses dynamic library

```
$ ll /home/snebel29/.pyenv/versions/*/lib/python*/lib-dynload/*cur*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 snebel29 snebel29  42620 Jan 28  2016 /home/snebel29/.pyenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_curses_panel.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 snebel29 snebel29 254035 Jan 28  2016 /home/snebel29/.pyenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_curses.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 snebel29 snebel29  42520 May 16  2015 /home/snebel29/.pyenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_curses_panel.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 snebel29 snebel29 254661 May 16  2015 /home/snebel29/.pyenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_curses.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 snebel29 snebel29 320512 Mar 15 11:50 /home/snebel29/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_curses.cpython-34m.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 snebel29 snebel29  46244 Mar 15 11:50 /home/snebel29/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_curses_panel.cpython-34m.so*
```

should point to `libncursesw.so.5`

```
$ ldd /home/snebel29/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_curses.cpython-34m.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffecad1000)
    libncursesw.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5 (0x00007f868e9d0000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f868e7a7000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f868e589000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f868e1c4000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f868dfc0000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f868ee1b000)
```

and somehow was pointing to `libncurses.so.5`, see here for my 2.7.6 interpreter where this is still faling

```
$ ldd /home/snebel29/.pyenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_curses.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcb3f60000)
    libncurses.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5 (0x00007feed55be000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007feed5395000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007feed5177000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007feed4db2000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007feed4bae000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007feed59f5000)
```

However I still don't get why on library works and not the other and specially why running with `root` account make it works...